# How to check if a field exists in SQL subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have to do a lot of queries with this kind of logic:

- Check if a table contains a record for a patient

  - If it does return then 'Yes'
  - Else return 'No'

Now, I want to create a procedure that will do this, so I tried to create a function that will do the above, but ended up in dynamic queries which is not possible in functions.

Is it possible to achieve this? How can I go about this?

PS:
Maybe something like:

```
select 
(IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Dtl_Patient WHERE Pk = 3990 select 'Yes' else select 'No')) as output from dtl_AllPatient;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just query the table and make your businesslogic go "yes" if there is a result and "no" if there isn't? That way you use the database for what it's for? If the actual problem is more complicated (like you want to put it in a bigger resultset), you could probably do simpler tricks like left-join and check for `null`, but hten you'd have to describe the problem more?

Comment: I have to query *different tables and columns*, which makes the problem quite really complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [**CASE**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT PatientID FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T2.PatientID =T1.PatientID)
       THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS PatientExists
FROM
Table1 T1
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT Pk FROM Dtl_Patient WHERE Pk = 3990) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS PatientExists
FROM dtl_AllPatient
```

check this [**EXISTS Condition**](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php)

The SQL EXISTS condition is considered "to be met" if the subquery returns at least one row.

Comment: As we are using EXISTS subquery will return True or False not resultset

Comment: I'm getting the error: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: Post the query you are using

Comment: It's very long but one of them is:
select....,
`CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT top(1) Pk FROM dtl_PatientA WHERE Pk = a.Pk) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS hasAdhere`

Comment: No need to use top(1) as I commented before "EXISTS will return True or False not multiple rows". May be error is coming from other part of query

Comment: Found the problem. Thanks